# write a programm to get asctec data

Tags: java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have successfully installed the ros asctec drivers. And they are working correctly. Now I want to write a litle java program and for this program I need the flight data, for example angel yaw. But how can I get the data into my java program. Can you give me some hints?

kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11280/write-a-programm-to-get-asctec-data/) by [Alex3](https://answers.ros.org/users/1109/alex3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to access the data from the quadrotor, the asctec_proc node provides a number of topics that you can subscribe to to get the desired information. A description of all of the topics can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/asctec_proc). To see them in the terminal, you can use 'rostopic echo /mav/imu' or the equivalent.

In order to get this information into a Java program, however, you must be running [rosjava](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava). Rosjava will provide you with access to these topics from Java. You can find some tips on installing [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2178/rosjavajar-missing-certain-packages?answer=3713#3713). You can then use the rosjava API to access the information you desire.

I hope that you find this useful. I can provide more specific examples of using rosjava if required.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1